# Skip system role at finetuned model?

Tags: openai-api

I have fine-tuned my model with openai  GPT-3.5 turbo.
It is working well. Only thing I have doubts do we really need everytime to send system content? I thought if its fine-tuned we dont need repeat system role in every request...